# Ошибка при обращении к битовому полю. микроконтроллер avr

Tags: c, avr

Есть массив структур ConfigLamp[CONFIG_AMOUNT].
Обращаюсь у нему следующим образом:

```
ConfigLamp[0].ValuePWM=123;
ConfigLamp[0].Flag.Bits.B0=1;
```

И вроде бы все пишется, но через несколько тактов, судя по симуляции, данные которые хранит данный массив затираются каким-то мусором.

В чем может быть проблема? Может кто подсказать ? был бы признателен.

Ниже код объявления массива и структур:

```
//Структура объеденения битовых полей.
struct UnionsBits
{
    unsigned B0:1;
    unsigned B1:1;
    unsigned B2:1;
    unsigned B3:1;
    unsigned B4:1;
    unsigned B5:1;
    unsigned B6:1;
    unsigned B7:1;
};
union Byte
{
    uint8_t Byte;
    struct UnionsBits Bits;
};
#define CONFIG_AMOUNT 1
//Определения нового типа.
typedef struct {
    uint8_t ValuePWM;
    union Byte Flag;
}Config;

Config ConfigLamp[CONFIG_AMOUNT]; //Массив структур.
```

Comment: А где код, в котором "данные затираются каким-то мусором"?

Comment: Добавил ниже. Он максимально очищен от всего для симкляции proteus

Comment: Здесь не делается "добавил ниже". Добавляйте новые данные в вопрос, а не в ответы самому себе.

Comment: Не знал, в следующий раз так и сделаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы все время вызываете

```
TWI_SendData(buf, 13);
```

где внутри оно копирует данные размера `13` в буфер размера `8`

```
#define TWI_BUFFER_SIZE  8 
volatile static uint8_t twiBuf[TWI_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Неудивительно, что где-то что-то будет затираться при вылете за пределы массива.

Comment: не дело не в этом.  для теста даже удалил из цикла TWI_SendData(buf, 13);

Comment: @Андрей Плотников: Это как это? Если удалить `TWI_SendData` из цикла, то у вас в `main` после присваивания битового поля вообще больше ничего делаться не будет. В какой же момент вы тогда наблюдаете ваше затирание?

Comment: ну тут выкладывал скрины https://radiokot.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=157698  Правда там еще не удаленна эта строчка без нее происходит тоже самое.

Comment: Упс извиняюсь походу это она все таки.

Answer (score 0):

```
Полный код :

#define F_CPU 16000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <avr/eeprom.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <util/twi.h>
//========================================================================
#define SET_BIT(port,bit)   port|=(1<<bit)
#define CLEAR_BIT(port,bit) port&= ~(1<<bit)
#define INV_BIT(port,bit)   port ^=(1<<bit)
//========================================================================
/*размер буфера TWI модуля*/
#define TWI_BUFFER_SIZE  8      
/****************************************************************************
  Статусные коды TWI модуля 
****************************************************************************/
/*Общие статусные коды */                    
#define TWI_START                  0x08  // состояние START сформировано 
#define TWI_REP_START              0x10  // состояние повторный START сформировано 
#define TWI_ARB_LOST               0x38  // был потерян приоритет 
/*Статусные коды ведущего передатчика*/                
#define TWI_MTX_ADR_ACK            0x18  // был передан пакет SLA+W и получено подтверждение
#define TWI_MTX_ADR_NACK           0x20  // был передан пает SLA+W и не получено подтверждение
#define TWI_MTX_DATA_ACK           0x28  // был передан байт данных и получено подтверждение  
#define TWI_MTX_DATA_NACK          0x30  // был передан байт данных и не получено подтверждение
/*Статусные коды ведущего приемника*/ 
#define TWI_MRX_ADR_ACK            0x40  // был передан пакет SLA+R и получено подтвеждение 
#define TWI_MRX_ADR_NACK           0x48  // был передан пакет SLA+R и не получено подтверждение 
#define TWI_MRX_DATA_ACK           0x50  // байт данных принят и передано подтверждение  
#define TWI_MRX_DATA_NACK          0x58  // был принят байт данных без подтверждения  
/*Другие статусные коды*/
#define TWI_NO_STATE               0xF8  // неопределенное состояние; TWINT = “0”
#define TWI_BUS_ERROR              0x00  // ошибка на шине из-за некоректных состояний СТАРТ или СТОП
/*Пользовательские коды*/
#define TWI_SUCCESS                0xff
/****************************************************************************
  Определения констант
****************************************************************************/
#define TWI_READ_BIT    0       // позиция R/W бита в адресном пакете
#define TWI_ADR_BITS    1       // позиция адреса в адресном пакете
#define TRUE            1
#define FALSE           0
#define TWSR_MASK       0xfc  

//Структура объеденения битовых полей.
struct UnionsBits
{
    unsigned B0:1;
    unsigned B1:1;
    unsigned B2:1;
    unsigned B3:1;
    unsigned B4:1;
    unsigned B5:1;
    unsigned B6:1;
    unsigned B7:1;
};
union Byte
{
    uint8_t Byte;
    struct UnionsBits Bits;
};
#define CONFIG_AMOUNT 1
//Определения нвого типа.
typedef struct {
    uint8_t ValuePWM;
    union Byte Flag;
}Config;

Config ConfigLamp[CONFIG_AMOUNT]; //Массив структур.


volatile static uint8_t twiBuf[TWI_BUFFER_SIZE];
volatile static uint8_t twiState = TWI_NO_STATE;      
volatile static uint8_t twiMsgSize;       
/*предделители для установки скорости обмена twi модуля*/
uint8_t pre[4] = {2, 8, 32, 128};
/****************************************************************************
 Инициализация и установка частоты SCL сигнала
****************************************************************************/
uint8_t TWI_MasterInit(uint16_t fr)
{
  uint8_t i;
  uint16_t twbrValue;

  for(i = 0; i<4; i++){
    twbrValue = ((((F_CPU)/1000UL)/fr)-16)/pre[i];
    if ((twbrValue > 0)&& (twbrValue < 256)){
       TWBR = (uint8_t)twbrValue;
       TWSR = i;
       TWDR = 0xFF;
       TWCR = (1<<TWEN);
       return TWI_SUCCESS;
    }
  }
  return 0;  
}    
/****************************************************************************
 Проверка - не занят ли TWI модуль. Используется внутри модуля
****************************************************************************/
static uint8_t TWI_TransceiverBusy(void)
{
  return (TWCR & (1<<TWIE));                 
}
/****************************************************************************
 Взять статус TWI модуля
****************************************************************************/
uint8_t TWI_GetState(void)
{
  while (TWI_TransceiverBusy());             
  return twiState;                        
}
/****************************************************************************
 Передать сообщение msg из msgSize байтов на TWI шину
****************************************************************************/
void TWI_SendData(uint8_t *msg, uint8_t msgSize)
{
  uint8_t i;

  while(TWI_TransceiverBusy());   //ждем, когда TWI модуль освободится             

  twiMsgSize = msgSize;           //сохряняем кол. байт для передачи             
  twiBuf[0]  = msg[0];            //и первый байт сообщения 

  if (!(msg[0] & (TRUE<<TWI_READ_BIT))){   //если первый байт типа SLA+W
    for (i = 1; i < msgSize; i++){         //то сохряняем остальную часть сообщения
      twiBuf[i] = msg[i];
    }
  }

  twiState = TWI_NO_STATE ;
  TWCR = (1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWIE)|(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA); //разрешаем прерывание и формируем состояние старт                            
}
/****************************************************************************
 Переписать полученные данные в буфер msg в количестве msgSize байт. 
****************************************************************************/
uint8_t TWI_GetData(uint8_t *msg, uint8_t msgSize)
{
  uint8_t i;

  while(TWI_TransceiverBusy());    //ждем, когда TWI модуль освободится 

  if(twiState == TWI_SUCCESS){     //если сообщение успешно принято,                         
    for(i = 0; i < msgSize; i++){  //то переписываем его из внутреннего буфера в переданный
      msg[i] = twiBuf[i];
    }
  }

  return twiState;                                   
}
/****************************************************************************
 Обработчик прерывания TWI модуля
****************************************************************************/
ISR(TWI_vect)
{
  static uint8_t ptr;
  uint8_t stat = TWSR & TWSR_MASK;

  switch (stat){

    case TWI_START:                   // состояние START сформировано 
    case TWI_REP_START:               // состояние повторный START сформировано        
       ptr = 0;      

    case TWI_MTX_ADR_ACK:             // был передан пакет SLA+W и получено подтверждение
    case TWI_MTX_DATA_ACK:            // был передан байт данных и получено подтверждение  
       if (ptr < twiMsgSize){
          TWDR = twiBuf[ptr];                    //загружаем в регистр данных следующий байт
          TWCR = (1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWIE)|(1<<TWINT); //сбрасываем флаг TWINT    
          ptr++;
       }
       else{
          twiState = TWI_SUCCESS;  
          TWCR = (1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTO)|(0<<TWIE); //формируем состояние СТОП, сбрасываем флаг, запрещаем прерывания
       }
       break;

    case TWI_MRX_DATA_ACK:          //байт данных принят и передано подтверждение  
       twiBuf[ptr] = TWDR;
       ptr++;

    case TWI_MRX_ADR_ACK:           //был передан пакет SLA+R и получено подтвеждение  
      if (ptr < (twiMsgSize-1)){
        TWCR = (1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWIE)|(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWEA);  //если это не предпоследний принятый байт, формируем подтверждение                             
      }
      else {
        TWCR = (1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWIE)|(1<<TWINT);            //если приняли предпоследний байт, подтверждение не формируем
      }    
      break; 

    case TWI_MRX_DATA_NACK:       //был принят байт данных без подтверждения      
      twiBuf[ptr] = TWDR;
      twiState = TWI_SUCCESS;  
      TWCR = (1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTO); //формируем состояние стоп
      break; 

    case TWI_ARB_LOST:          //был потерян приоритет 
      TWCR = (1<<TWEN)|(1<<TWIE)|(1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA); // сбрасываем флаг TWINT, формируем повторный СТАРТ
      break;

    case TWI_MTX_ADR_NACK:      // был передан пает SLA+W и не получено подтверждение
    case TWI_MRX_ADR_NACK:      // был передан пакет SLA+R и не получено подтверждение    
    case TWI_MTX_DATA_NACK:     // был передан байт данных и не получено подтверждение
    case TWI_BUS_ERROR:         // ошибка на шине из-за некоректных состояний СТАРТ или СТОП
    default:     
      twiState = stat;                                                                                    
      TWCR = (1<<TWEN)|(0<<TWIE)|(0<<TWINT)|(0<<TWEA)|(0<<TWSTA)|(0<<TWSTO)|(0<<TWWC); //запретить прерывание                              
  }
}
#define ADR    0x30
uint8_t buf[13]={0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA,0xAA};
int main(void)
{
    TWI_MasterInit(100);
    sei();
    /*подготавливаем сообщение*/
    buf[0] = (ADR<<1);  //адресный пакет
    buf[1] = 0;                  //адрес регистра
    buf[2] = 0xfa;           //значение секунд
    buf[3] = 0xfb;           //значение минут 
    /*отправляем его*/
    TWI_SendData(buf, 13);
    ConfigLamp[0].ValuePWM=123;
    ConfigLamp[0].Flag.Bits.B0=1;
    while(1)
    {
        TWI_SendData(buf, 13);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Здесь так не делается. Добавляйте новые данные в *вопрос*, а не в ответы самому себе.